# Laravel set collation for join (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to move plain SQL query to Laravel query builder.

It's not my first time doing this, but now a "different case has popped up".

I need to set collation for join and in plain SQL it's no problem:

```
"...
LEFT OUTER JOIN " . $pltable1 . " on PL01001=supplier collate Latvian_BIN
..."
```

Laravel throws error when I try:

```
->leftJoin($pltable1, "PL01001", "=", "supplier");
```

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latvian_BIN" in the equal to
>   operation.

I know it's because I didn't specify a collation for join but I have no clue of how to do this. Has anyone encountered something like this and found solution?

P.S. I can't change default collation on table itself

Comment: You can always search in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?p=1&q=collation&unscoped_q=collation) it seems that you need to use RAW statement.

Comment: @Kyslik As far as I have understood reading source code: everything that includes "collation" is about setting collation for migration. Also what do you think by "RAW statement"? ->raw("[plain SQL join]") and ->leftJoin(DB::raw("[plain SQL join]")) doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remembered I asked this question and realized I'v found solution to this problem:

```
DB::table('table1')
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.column', '=', DB::raw('table2.column collate Latvian_BIN'))
    ->get();
```

Basically all that is required is to wrap one column and collation in DB::raw()
Hope this helps to someone someday